# Ionic background task at a specific time?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, background-process

Q: how can I do a task that repeats every **x minutes** in background?

Comment: We need more deatils on your set-up: are you using Cordova or Capacitor? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use js setTimeout function.

Like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
 alert("Hello"); 
}, 3000);
```

3000 is the amount of time in ms. so this alert will be shown every 3 seconds.

to run it under any condition put it in app.component.ts